# WCF Service with large parameters

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-client

I've looked at a number of similar topics on SO, but haven't found one that helps with this.

Have a WCF service that takes in XML to process.  The XML file I'm reading from is ~600K.

The call works for small xml files (most of the time), but on the larger files I get the error:

> System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException:
>   An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party. See the inner FaultException for the fault code and detail.

where the inner exception is:

> System.ServiceModel.FaultException: 
>   The message could not be processed. This is most likely because the action 'http://tempuri.org/ISapListener/ProcessSapRoles' is incorrect or because the message contains an invalid or expired security context token or because there is a mismatch between bindings. The security context token would be invalid if the service aborted the channel due to inactivity. To prevent the service from aborting idle sessions prematurely increase the Receive timeout on the service endpoint's binding.

Like I say... it works for small files, and my open, send, receive, close, and inactivity timeouts are all set to 10 minutes.  It fails in about 20-30 seconds.

Also, the clock on the server and client are perfectly in sync (I've seen that posted as an answer).

My config files as they currently stand (I've played with a lot of settings):

Server:

```
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="wsHttpBinding_Custom" closeTimeout="00:00:10"
             openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
             sendTimeout="00:10:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" 
             transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
             messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" 
             useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false"
             maxReceivedMessageSize="1024768"            
             maxBufferPoolSize="1024768" >
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxBytesPerRead="4096" 
                    maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" 
                       enabled="false" />
      <security mode="Message">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None" 
                   realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" 
                 negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                 algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="CSA.GS3.Services.SapListenerBehavior" 
           name="CSA.GS3.Services.SapListener">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding"  
              bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBinding_Custom" 
              contract="CSA.GS3.Services.ISapListener">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" 
              contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="CSA.GS3.Services.SapListenerBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Client:

```
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WSHttpBinding_ISapListener1" 
             closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" 
             receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
             bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false"
             hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
             messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" 
             useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false"
             maxBufferPoolSize="1024768" 
             maxReceivedMessageSize="1024768">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxBytesPerRead="4096" 
                    maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                       enabled="false" />
      <security mode="Message">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
          realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" 
                 negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                 algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://gs3-test.us.tycoelectronics.com/SapListener/SapListener.svc"
            binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_ISapListener1"
            contract="Gs3TestSapListener.ISapListener" 
            name="WSHttpBinding_ISapListener1">
    <identity>
      <dns value="localhost" />
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
</client>
```

I do have tracing enabled on the service, but I can't make sense out of the log files.

Other exceptions I've received while playing with the config settings:

> System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException
>   Secure channel cannot be opened because security negotiation with the remote endpoint has failed.

and

> System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException
>   The requested service, 'http://../SapListener.svc' could not be activated.

Comment: Does it always fail for large files?

Comment: Yes... small ones usually work, though I was having some issues on occasion with those, but usually either restarting the service or trying again would fix it

Comment: By the way is there a situation where it works locally but not against a remote client? That is you have a test client that runs locally and sends the large content and it does not fail?

Comment: It got a little confusing as to what scenarios were working and what weren't.  At one point I was sure it was working locally, but not when I deployed it to the server, I won't swear to that, though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work with the following configuration:

Server:

```
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="wsHttpBinding_Custom"
             closeTimeout="00:10:00"
             openTimeout="00:10:00"
             receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
             sendTimeout="00:10:00"
             maxReceivedMessageSize="2097152"
             bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" 
             hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
             maxBufferPoolSize="2097152" messageEncoding="Text"
             textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxBytesPerRead="4096" 
                    maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="false" />
      <security mode="Message">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None" 
                   realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true" 
                 algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Client:

```
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WSHttpBinding_ISapListener1" closeTimeout="00:10:00"
             openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
             bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" 
             hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
             maxBufferPoolSize="2097152" 
             maxReceivedMessageSize="2097152"
             messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
             allowCookies="false">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxBytesPerRead="4096" 
                    maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                       enabled="false" />
      <security mode="Message">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
                   realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                 algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

The only difference I can see is that I bumped up the maxReceivedMessageSize and maxBufferPoolSize... maybe I'm missing something else?  If that was the issue, then the problem was that my overhead for the call was adding an additional 400+K to the 600K xml data I was sending

Comment: Be also careful with maximum array objects count, and maximum object size etc.  Stuff like this are not well documented in WCF, and is sometimes a pain to diagnose.

Comment: Thanks for the warning... I will look into those

Answer (score 0):

If you think being able to make sense out of log files will help here, use svcTraceViewer. Just make sure you've actually set up tracing correctly. I have an article on my blog about this.
[svcTraveViewer Debugging WCF Services](http://www.matlus.com/svctraceviewer-debugging-wcf-sevices/)

As regards large payloads, you may want to take a look at this MSDN article.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx

In particular Streaming Data.

Comment: Thanks... I was using svcTraceViewer : \  There were no obvious errors or warnings, only information and I think start/stops.  I figured I just didn't know what to look for.  I'll take a closer look at those articles.

Comment: The reason I didn't go with streaming initially is because I need all of the data to process it... I'm running linq queries against the xml, which is meaningless until all of the xml is read

Comment: On the WCF end, once you receive your document you can process it as you normally do. I've not done this using WCF but I can't imagine that the whole pipeline has to rely on streaming. Streaming is between the client end and server end. Once the server "receives" the document, all other processing should remain the same.

Comment: Sure, but it was my understanding that the benefit of streaming was that you didn't need to wait on the data coming in to begin processing, though.  I suppose I could do it solely to get around having to figure out the buffer sizes; the error I'm seeing might go away in the process...

Answer (score 0):

```
System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException
The requested service, 'http://../SapListener.svc' could not be activated.
```

This could be a compilation error ou invalid configuration.

Is it WCF 4.0? Then you could remove your custom configuration and use automatic bindings. I also suggest you to try a binding other than wsHttpBinding, like basicHttpBinding.

Comment: More likely invalid config, since there hasn't been a need to recompile.  Using 3.5, unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

If possible and acceptable to client, you can break down the file into smaller chunks and send across, provided you don't have digital certificate etc and sorting options at client side.